# `getLine` function skipping the final, blank line in an input file

Tags: c++, file, c++11, file-io

I want to find out the character length of each of the lines in a separate file, which is `test.txt`. `test.txt` contains two lines: the first contains `hello`, and the second is blank.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("test.txt");
    string currline;

    while (getline(inFile, currline)) {
      cout << currline.length() << endl;
    }
}
```

When executing this program and inputting 'test.txt', I was expecting the output to be `5 0`. However, the output was simply `5`, which meant that the second line of `test.txt` was being ignored. How do I solve this issue without modifying the input file, or using a new modified file?

Comment: That's actually correct. Even discounting the common requirement that _all_ lines end with a newline, _this_ final line has no content before EOF. No data before EOF --> no line. (Add a space or something to see a line. In other words, the final line cannot have zero characters.)

Answer (score 0):

Your test.txt contains only one line - "hello" with a trailing '\n', rather than two lines.